# HTML div doesn't wrap <i> tag

Tags: html, css, styles

I am trying to make my div wrap the `<i>` tag however it doesn't wrap, the height is always higher of my div, and my `<i>` tag has no padding or margin, i tried many things but doesn't work, i am adding my style and the html code, i am also going to add some screenshots

**CSS**

```
<style>
.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}

.button-content-ic {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

body, section, div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-content-ic">
                    <i style="color: #fff;" class="material-icons">menu</i>                </div>
```

**SCREENSHOTS**

**tag**

[image]

**wrapper tag**

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you looking for:

```css
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: inherit;
  display: block!important;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  color: #ffffff;
}
.button-content-ic {
  background-color: #555555;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
body,
section,
div,
i {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="button-content-ic"><i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Im sorry but what is the difference from what i posted?

Comment: Did you run the code snippet? The only different here is that i use `display: block;` instead `display: inline-block;` on `.material-icons`.